# Set Eclipse "Refresh using native hooks or polling" to true through java code?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, refresh, workspace

Is there a way to set "Preferences -> General -> Workspace -> Refresh using native hooks or polling" to true through java code?
I'm developing an eclipse plugin that changes the resources a lot and therefore, the projects are always out of sync.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer:

```
IEclipsePreferences prefs = InstanceScope.INSTANCE.getNode("org.eclipse.core.resources");
prefs.putBoolean(ResourcesPlugin.PREF_AUTO_REFRESH, true);
prefs.flush();
```

Thanks all.